# Asterisk nat=force_rport,comedia with routing

Tags: asterisk

I have a setup where the phones are in 2 subnetwork, but only routing used between them not real NAT.

```
10.4.0.40 < Asterisk PBX
10.4.0.9  < Phone 1
10.1.0.66 < Phone 2
```

Phone 1 and the PBX are on the same network, for phone2 there is a route through 10.4.0.1. Phone2 also has a route back to the 10.4.0.0/24 network.

Is there a point using:

nat=force_rport,comedia

in this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, since you don't have a NAT on their way. Why bother ? I'd even suggest `nat=no` option, make it simplier.